# CMake not including library files when I use FetchContent

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a project where the CMake structure looks like this:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
project(overflow VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(src)

enable_testing()
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(test)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

set(HEADER_FILES overflow.h)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(overflow ${HEADER_FILES})

link_libraries(overflow PRIVATE Boost::uuid) # Fails with `target_`
```

These work fine. However, I get an error when I set up GTest as shown below in my test directory.

test/CMakeLists.txt

```
## Setup GTest
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929.zip
)
### For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

add_executable(overflowtest overflow.i.t.cpp)

target_link_libraries(overflowtest PRIVATE
        overflow
        gtest
        gtest_main)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(overflowtest)
```

CMake builds correctly, but when I run the test, the error in overflow.h is:

```
boost/uuid/uuid.hpp: No such file or directory
```

What I find strange is that if I change my settings so that test/CMakeLists.txt looks like:

test/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(overflowtest overflow.i.t.cpp)

target_link_libraries(overflowtest PRIVATE
        overflow
        GTest::gtest
        GTest::gtest_main)
```

There are no errors and it runs correctly. Can someone please explain why using the `FetchContent` method recommended by Google seems to break my project?

Comment: Build with verbose output and compare your build flags.  Keep an eye on your include paths.

Comment: If `overflow` has a public dependency on boost::uuid then you should be linking to `Boost::uuid` with `PUBLIC` rather than `PRIVATE`. My guess would be that `find_package(GTest` brings in boost too but `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)` doesn't

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've tried that and it didn't fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @StephenNewell Thanks. I see that the passing build includes the overflow library in the log line like `-o overflowtest  ../src/liboverflow.a` , while the failing build does not, but that's as far as I've gone. My guess is it's something to do with `FetchContent` but I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm not sure and hoping I can get some help here.

Comment: "These work fine." - Eh? It cannot work fine. Firstly, you replace `target_link_libraries` with `link_libraries` call, which is useless (it affects only on further libraries in the same `CMakeLists.txt` or inner one). Second, your `overflow` library has **no sources**, so CMake should fail to configure the project because it cannot decide which linker language to use for it. It you want to define header-only library, you need to declare it `INTERFACE` keyword.

Comment: "but when I run the test, the error in `overflow.h` is" - This is not when you run the test. The error occurred when you **build** (compile) the test executable. During compilation of `overflowtest` the header `boost/uuid/uuid.hpp` cannot be found because neither include directory nor linked Boost library of `overflow` library are propagated to the `overflowtest` executable. Only **target** properties can be propagated, which are defined with commands started with `target_`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It does work fine in my project. I'm not including the full example here because I want my question to be simpler to read. There are sources in the project. 

Regarding `link_libraries`, that has not caused any issues until now with the changes in test/CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have used `target_link_libraries` instead and it still exhibits the same behaviour, where it does not link the overflow library.

Comment: In `src/CMakeLists.txt` you tried to use `target_link_libraries` with PUBLIC keyword, didn't you? PRIVATE linkage is not propagated when one links with the library.

Comment: CMake should link with the library, specified in `target_link_libraries` call. Absence of real linking means bug in CMake. But for reproduce the bug we need **complete** example, not just part of files. Note, that "complete" doesn't imply a "production code of thousands of lines". It means [mcve], as you have been asked in [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I apologize, you were right about using `target_link_libraries` with PUBLIC keyword. Just cross-checked that and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your are NOT setting

```
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\${ORIGIN}")
```

Anywhere in your code.  This will make it expect the libraries in the same folder as the program.

Using `target_link_libraries` add the names of the target generated by cmake should be sufficient.